# Using DualShock 4 and DualSense controller over Bluetooth

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, games

For some time I've used a DS4 controller over Bluetooth to play games on my Linux Box.
Details about the box:

- Hardware: Asrock Beebox N3150
- OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04.3
- Software: Kodi + Retroarch

Now I got a DualSense controller. I can pair it over Bluetooth to use it the same way than the DS4. I can still use the DS4 if I disconnect the DualSense controller first. But I cannot get the 2 controllers working at the same time.

What I've tried:

- Testing the same thing on another computer (also based on Ubuntu 20.04) => it works, I can play a multiplayer game on Retroarch
- Testing to install a newer kernel on the box, namely the 5.13 kernel (through HWE as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)) in order to get the official hid_playstation driver supported by Sony => it did not helped, although I ensured that I was using the correct driver for the DualSense
- Testing using first a USB connection to autorise the device, then connect over Bluetooth => no improvement
- Testing using one controller over Bluetooth, the other one over USB => it works

What I suspect (hypothesis - I may be wrong):

- The issue may not be linked to the Bluetooth connection. I used `bluetoothctl` to pair my devices, and encountered no problem in the pairing process. `blueoothctl` told me that the device was paired, and the LED on the devices moved from blinking to fix color
- The issue is probably linked to the driver, or in any other stuff related to communicating with the device: when the second controller (either DualSense or DS4) is connected, it stays with a fixed color (grey for the DS4, blue for the DualSense) for some time (usually less than 1 minute) and then shutdown. So I guess it means that it's Bluetooth-connected, but it does not get the answer that it wants after some time.

Does somebody can help me to correct this problem?
I can provide log of whatever is needed, and go back and forth from 5.4 to 5.13 kernel (but I'm not sure it's needed because it does work one controller at a time on 5.4).